# Need help AWK script

Tags: awk

Could you let me know how to print "user.%" string in below text by awk?
The value of 'user' is not fixed and the number of strings in '( )' are not fixed.

```
start user1.table% NOT (%OLD, %2016%)  user.% another strings
```

**UPDATE**

It is the basis of SQL processing. $2 means schema.table but here user can use '%' and also exclude by NOT keyword. It ends with ')'. The next one is a second schema.table and that is the one I want to catch. 
I think I should parse the string after ')' with a regular expression but failed.

Regular expression:

```
[)]\s+(\S+)
```

Above expression can be used to catch that string I guess.
How can I apply this one in awk script(Not one liner).

Comment: Huh? Is this some sort of Windows batch file? What is user% - a batch variable? Some SQL thing? You need to provide more context.

Comment: Actually, it is the basis of SQL processing. $2 means schema.table but here user can use '%' and also exclude by NOT keyword. It ends with ')'. The next one is a second schema.table and that is the one I want to catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structure of the query keeps the same, you can use this:

```
awk -F'[).]' '{print $3".%"}'
```

I'm using the closing parenthesis or the literal dot as the delimiter. Doing so the value of interest is in field 3.

While it is simple it leaves some whitespace in front of user. We can enhance the field delimiter regex to fix this:

```
awk -F')[[:space:]]*|[.]' '{print $3".%"}'
```

---

Btw, you may use this sed command alternatively:

```
sed 's/.*)[[:space:]]*\([^.]*\).*/\1.%/'
```

or if you have GNU grep, use this:

```
grep -oP '\)\s*\K[^%]*%'
```

Comment: It works well in one liner. BTW, when I put it in awk script, it just prints NOT.%. What is wrong? begin {FS=")[[:space:]]*|[.]";} {print $3".%"}

Comment: Why are you setting `FS=''`? FS should be `')[[:space:]]*|[.]'`

Comment: In awk script, I used FS=")[[:space:]]*|[.]";

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyhow, I can't reproduce that. Looks like you did not specified your input data properly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (GNU awk):

```
awk '{match($0, /[)] +([^ ]+)/, var);print var[1];}'
```

You need to match first (GNU awk function).

Comment: @POW wrt `you cannot use \s since awk does not support it.` - yes it does. Or at least the version of awk you are using does. The 3rd arg to `match()` is gawk-specific so since you're already using gawk you can cheerfully use other gawk extensions like `\s` too. You should state in your answer that it's gawk-specific btw.

Answer (score 1):

Given your posted sample input, all you need is:

```
awk '{print $6}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo 'start user1.table% NOT (%OLD, %2016%)  user.% another strings' |
    awk '{print $6}'
user.%
```

If that doesn't work for you then your posted sample input isn't representative enough of your real input so edit your question to include a few lines of truly representative sample input and the expected output given that input.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I updated the question saying 'the number of strings in ' ( ) ' are not fixed.

Comment: You should have updated your sample input and expected output to show some lines with different layouts. Stating it in the text is only partially useful - we need something we can test a potential solution against.